# JavaScript in Vaadin 7 doesn't work on InternetExplorer 11

Tags: javascript, java, internet-explorer, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a web application in Vaadin 7, I use JavaScript and it works on Google Chrome, but doesn't on IE 11. This is my way of to use JavaScript (I don't want doing it with Java if it's possible)

```
com.vaadin.ui.JavaScript.getCurrent().addFunction("left", new JavaScriptFunction(){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Override
        public void call(JsonArray arguments) {

            zinkonaux.executeJs(""
                        + "var box = document.querySelector('.divobjetos');"
                        + "var pos = window.getComputedStyle(box,null).getPropertyValue('left');"
                        + "pos = parseInt(pos);"
                        + "pos = pos + 300;"
                        + "box.style.left = pos+'px';"
                    );

        }
    });
```

My problem is:
In IE the javascript function does not work, I want to click on one of the previous div, another scroll, like a carousel effect, but in IE when clicking does not make the effect and in the development window there are no errors

Comment: Please define "_doesn't work_". Also, make sure IE is running the app in standards mode.

Comment: I have two tags in html (with CustomLayout) `<div class="left" onclick="left()"></div><div class="right" onclick="right()"></div>`

On Google Chrome if I click in some div before, the function javascript works, but on IE doesn't

Comment: WORKS! What does that mean? In IE the script throws stones to neighbour's windows? "Doesn't work" is not a problem description. Please explain what you want your code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: In IE the javascript function does not work, I want to click on one of the previous div, another scroll, like a carousel effect, but in IE when clicking does not make the effect and in the development window there are no errors

Comment: Now, that is a good explanation, please add it to the question too. Btw. There's nothing in the JS code, which wouldn't "work" in IE11.

Comment: Try using an anchor for your left and right divs i.e. <a href="javascript:left();">left</a>

Comment: I tried, but nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not solve the JavaScript error in IE, specifically to change the position of the inner div between the left and right containers, use in each one a button that in its ClickListener modified the style with:

Styles styles = Page.getCurrent().getStyles();
styles.add(".divscroll .divobjects { left: "+positionInfoTags+"px !important }");

My html code was this:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="left" location="moveLeft"></div>
     <div class="right" location="moveRight"></div>
     <div class="divscroll">
        <div class="divobjects" location="infoTags">
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving your Javascript into a separate file. If you want the JS method to be available throughout your application you could use the @JavaScript annotation on your UI class.

```
package com.company

@JavaScript("test.js")
public class MyUI extends UI 
{
...
```

Then you need to put test.js into your resources folder (if you're using maven) in the folder /com/company/test.js which would look something like this.

```
function left()
{
    var box = document.querySelector('.divobjetos');"
    var pos = window.getComputedStyle(box,null).getPropertyValue('left');"
    pos = parseInt(pos);"
    pos = pos + 300;"
    box.style.left = pos+'px';
}
```

Comment: Hello,,
I do not use maven, but I have already imported jquery before, I've done what you told me, but it still does not work in IE